# Display/edit/update Excel file on website

Tags: javascript, php, excel

I have a Excel file that I want to display and edit on a Website.
I know displaying is possible with PHPExcel.
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel
Maybe this can help? https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx
The question is: is it possible to have the Excel file on the website and two cells being editable for the user. The information in the Excel file would most likely change after calculating the file again, if the cells got changed. I couldn't find information about that online, so I ask you guys. Maybe it's not possible at all. In that case what would be your recommendation to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: It's possible, but you'll have to write some code to do it.... if you only want 2 cells to be editable, a form might be easier

Comment: Okay, if I think about it, I don't really have to display the Excel sheet on the Website.
So, would it be possible to make a form that gets the 2 cells, insert the cells into the sheet in the Background, update the sheet and then offer it as a download?

Comment: That's pretty easy to do, yes

Comment: A form with PHP is not a problem. How would you do the rest? Insert the values in Excel with PHPExcel? How do I then update the Excel sheet? The Excel sheet has some vlookups in it, is that a problem?

Comment: Yes I'd insert the values into the template using PHPExcel. What do you mean by "update the Excel sheet"? Insert the values, save to file and offer as download..... what updating actually needs doing (aside from the inserted values) that Excel doesn't do itself?

Comment: The values in the sheet are dependent on the 2 cells. I got a lot of vlookups in the Excel sheet that Change with These 2 cells. By "updating" I'm talking about getting the new values from the vlookup.

Comment: But surely the whole point of Excel is that it does these calculations.... or do you need to display the results of those calculations to your users before they download the file? (and even then, PHPExcel can execute the calculations for those formula cells)

Comment: No, not really. The best Thing would be to just have a form with two Inputs. Put These in the Excel sheet and then download the file as a pdf.

Comment: So you want it as a PDF rather than as an actual Excel file; PHPExcel should automatically update all calculations in the spreadsheet when you save as PDF

Comment: Yes, pdf would even be better. Because it's a Report and the People who download it don't have to edit it anymore. So that would be the best. I'll talk to my Supervisor about it and then probably implement it beginning of next week. Thank you very much for your help! I'll come back if I should have Problems with the implementation